# Ontology based search

Tags: solr, nlp, stanford-nlp, ontology, protege

I am developing ontology-based web page search engine. We have a lot of web pages hosted by different applications.

All the searchable web pages are captured in ontology along with what information it contains, dimensions of information, URL, parameters, etc.

I wrote one page like google where the user can write search text, and I want to show all meaningful web pages link which matches closely with his query.

My question is more on technology stack.

1. What is the best way to index and do a search on ontology? - So far I am thinking of doing it in Solr but not sure how can Index different triples in Solr and what should be my design approach.
2. Understanding user search text and translating into a query which can be executed on Ontology. - May be NLP?

Please advice and it would be great if solution can be explained in detail.

Comment: Provide more info like the source of data (i.e) either you are fetching the data from a particular source or you want to crawl along the web pages?

Comment: Sasikumar, all the individual searchable web pages are captured in ontology with their metadata like web page title, name, url, parameters etc.
I want to do a search on ontology and show a link of web page from ontology. I do not want to crawl all webpages. 

Please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Yes kindly send me more information. Because you need to save the data into the SOLR server before searching right? Even google crawls all the data and then from the data they crawled, is being used in the google search. One more question for you is that do you want to have the artificial intelligence in the SOLR query formation? @user3222372

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NER and Lucene solved my requirement

Comment: Hi user3222372, Could you share more details on the pipeline you used, the steps for getting the data from source into SOLR and where did NER exactly fit in. Thanks in advance.